# TensorFlow: Is fitting in small step increments equivalent to fitting in 1 large increment?

Tags: tensorflow

I made a TensorFlow estimator with a certain model function:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
    model_fn=_model_fn_for_penguin_model,
    model_dir=/tmp/penguin_classification,
    config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(
       save_summary_steps=5))
```

And then called `estimator.fit` to train the model. I noticed that if I train in small step increments (not batch size) like 10, the OptimizeLoss metric converges:

```
step_increment = 10
for step in xrange(0, 1e6, step_increment):
  # Train for certain increment of steps.
  estimator.fit(
      input_fn=_input_fn_for_train, steps=step_increment)
```

I can tell based on TensorBoard (oddly, loss for my evaluation data set actually increases ... but that might be an irrelevant problem)

[image]

However, if I use a much bigger step increment size such as 200, the loss fluctuates around:

```
step_increment = 200
for step in xrange(0, 1e6, step_increment):
  # Train for certain increment of steps.
  estimator.fit(
      input_fn=_input_fn_for_train, steps=step_increment)
```

This confuses me because in my opinion, the above 2 code snippets should do the same thing at the end of the day: train a model for a million steps. Is that not the case?

I do not believe this stems from random seeding - I can reproduce this behavior consistently.

Here is the input function.

```
def make_input_fn(mode):
  def internal_input_fn():
    include_target = mode != tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.INFER
    feature_spec = tf.contrib.layers.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(
        feature_columns=_get_feature_columns(
            include_target_column=include_target))
    feature_map = tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features(
        batch_size=100,
        features=feature_spec,
        file_pattern=os.path.join("/tmp", mode + ".tfrecord"),
        queue_capacity=250,
        randomize_input=True,
        reader=tf.TFRecordReader)
    target = feature_map.pop() if include_target else None
    return feature_map, target
  return internal_input_fn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These calls should be equivalent, but one thing to keep in mind is the behavior of your input_fn. If it does no randomization, for example, the first case can loop over as much as 1M training examples, while the second one will just revisit the same 200 examples many times.

Comment: I think my input function (posted) does do randomization. Maybe the randomization does not work with `tf.TFRecordReader`?

Comment: Randomization works with recordreader, but maybe you're not randomizing enough.